# Is it a bad habit to initialize a unique_ptr using reset?

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

When I need to have a data member which is a type of `std::unique_ptr<A>`, then I have usually used `std::unique::reset()` to initialize this `unique_ptr` with a new object.

The following is a simplified example:

```
class A {
 public:
  void SetValue(int x) {
    data_.reset(new B(x));
  }

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<B> data_;
};
```

In the code review, one reviewer mentioned that it is a bad habit and he asked me not to use `reset()` if possible. Instead, he suggested to use the following methods:

```
std::make_unique
```

or a template function like the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct MakeUniqueResult {
  using scalar = std::unique_ptr<T>;
};
template <typename T, typename... Args>
typename internal::MakeUniqueResult<T>::scalar
MakeUnique(Args&&... args) {  
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(
      new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));  
}
```

Are there some special reasons to avoid using `std::unique_ptr::reset()` in the above case?

Comment: Just a difference of opinions. Some ppl like to see reset, some like to see move assignment invoked. Internal mechanincs are the same.

Comment: The next edit of the code could introduce some operation between the call to `new` and the call to `reset()`. At this point, what was merely a 'bad smell' becomes a problem.

Comment: @RichardHodges, how is it possible if they are on the same line?

Comment: You're not *initializing* when you call `reset`. You're changing the state of an already existing object. It makes little sense not to initialize an object that is useless uninitialized.

Comment: In this example it (data_) is initialized automatically by its default constructor, isn't it?

Comment: @RichardHodges, One would hope that by now, developers would recognize `new` as a potential source of problems and keep uses to a single action per statement - wrapping the returned pointer :/

Comment: @chris this is the purpose of the _standard_ idiom, `make_unique<>`

Comment: @RichardHodges, Of course, but it's not applicable everywhere. It works on an existing pointer, sure. It doesn't work when you have a custom deleter. It also doesn't work perfectly when constructing a `unique_ptr<Base>` with `Derived` constructor arguments. It's great in most cases, but doesn't eliminate `new` completely without more helpers (as with creating before `make_unique` got standardized). There's an item in Effective Modern C++ to keep `new` limited to a single wrapping statement. It's best to avoid `new` in general, but that's still good advice when it applies.

Comment: no, that's true. But there's nothing to stop a developer encapsulating the construction of a unique_ptr with a custom deleter within a documented utility function. This takes the call to `new` out of mainline code and keeps it safely in a known maintenance hotspot. I believe this what the OPs code reviewers are driving at.

Comment: @RichardHodges, Yes, that's what I meant with the last part. This applies kind of the same way as having your own `make_unique` would in pre-C++14 code. And I double checked my statement, It's the latter part of an item that says to prefer the `make_` functions rather than an item all on its own.

Comment: Dear original questioner: you should change the tag as a C++14 question since C++11 does not have `make_unique`

Comment: @chris understood. I think we're in agreement.

Comment: Voting to re-open.  There are factual objective answers available to the question "Are there some special reasons to avoid using std::unique_ptr::reset in the above case?"

Answer (score 11):

In your example, the effect is the same whether you use `std::make_unique` or `std::unique_ptr::reset` with new.

But in more interesting code, using `std::make_unique` solves some exception safety issues, and that's why your code reviewer is suggesting to make it a habit.

Consider what happens if you try to create two unique pointers at once:

```
Frobnicate(std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo), std::unique_ptr<Bar>(new Bar(3)));
```

The compiler has to do a bunch of work to create those two parameters, and it has a lot of flexibility in the order it can do that work.  If one of the constructors throws an exception, the memory allocated for the other one may or may not be cleaned up.

But if you use `std::make_unique`:

```
Frobnicate(std::make_unique<Foo>(), std::make_unique<Bar>(3));
```

The temporary unique_ptrs will immediately own their respective objects and thus be able to clean them up if creating the other one throws an exception.

For exception safety, and the general guideline of avoiding using new and delete directly, it's a good habit to use `std::make_unique` every time.